# Restangular won't change Http Content-Type

Tags: json, angularjs, html, sails.js, restangular

In order to send a file as part of my form, I **changed the content type to "multipart/form-data"**, but when I **check the console, it's still using application/json;charset=utf-8** And Node.js (with Sails.js framework) prints an error saying it's invalid JSON.

Here is the code:

```
$rootScope.objects.user.withHttpConfig({
    transformRequest: angular.identity
}).customPUT($scope.objects.user, "", { // user object contains a file
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data" // should change content-type. I've tried using `undefined` as well
}).then(function(resp) {
    if (resp == "OK") {
        $scope.successes = [{
            msg: "Saved"
        }];
    }
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    $scope.errors = err.data.errors;
});
```

The "Inspect Network Request" tab in Google Chrome reads:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Referer:    http://localhost:1337/user/settings
Host:   localhost:1337
DNT:    1
Content-Type:   application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 505679
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
```

Comment: shouldnt the header parameter be the fourth argument?

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods
 See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933574/restangular-not-setting-headers-on-post?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment above and According to docs you should pass headers as fourth parameter. So your code should be

```
    $rootScope.objects.user.withHttpConfig({
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).customPUT(
         $scope.objects.user,
          undefined,
          undefined, 
         {
             'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
         }
   ).then(function(resp) {
        if (resp == "OK") {
            $scope.successes = [{
                msg: "Saved"
            }];
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        $scope.errors = err.data.errors;
    });
```

Reference url : https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods